# Is there support for HP's Scan to Computer feature?

Tags: scanner, hp

I tried to find out if there is any support for HP's "Scan to Computer" feature on Linux but had a hard time to find any useful information on hplib page or in the HP developer forums. Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0):

I have linux version of HP Device Manager 15.0 (qt4) with HPLIP software version 3.21.10 installed on openSUSE leap 15.5.   It offers scan function (uses xsane commandline process).  The xsane process offers option to scan results to current computer.